# Does Xamarin Test Cloud support React Native apps on iOS Devices?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have build an app using React Native, and are currently looking for a test cloud service.

Xamarin looks like a good choice, but does it work with React Native?

Comment: AFAIK, XTC is agnostic about the technology used to build the app.

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin UI test doesn't care about how you have compiled your app, it's enough that when launched your app renders native component and React Native makes exactly this. So you can use it, for instance, with native Android and iOS, with Titanium, with Native Script, but not with Ionic and all the Cordova based frameworks.
You could have problems also if inside your app you used a lot of webviews.